# How can I set anonymous bookmarks in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2?

Tags: intellij-idea, key, bookmarks

Following that [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-bookmarks.html) I see how to create a bookmarks with mnemonics.
But I can't see how to create a anonymous bookmark.

I can accomplish this task trough the `Main_menu > Navigate > Bookmarks > Toggle Bookmark F11`.

If I use the `F11` key I can't create the anonymous one.

I am using a mac (`fn+F11`).

How could I do that using the key? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your Mac has following settings:

1. Settings > Keyboard > Use F1, F2 etc. keys as a standard function **is checked**
2. Settings > Mission Control - make sure **none of them using <kbd>F11</kbd>**, by
   default, **Show Desktop** is configured to use <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Then if you click <kbd>F11</kbd>, it should add/remove bookmarks.

Comment: Exactly that. Now I dont need even to use fn+ . Tks